# Как считать список файлов JSON по очереди? C#

Tags: c#, wpf, json

Есть файлы в формате JSON. В их храниться информация о пользователях и их показателях за каждый день. Мне нужно эти показатели считать. Но проблема в том, что каждый день это отдельный файл. Как с этим быть?

вот класс:

```
    class DataJson
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Steps { get; set; }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        String response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.DownloadData($"http://slova.by/JSON_test/Files/day1.json"));

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJson[]>(response);
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста ваш код, как вы читаете сейчас? Еще покажите структуру JSON файла, сейчас видно только фрагмент, вы можете вставить JSON текстом в впорос, а не скриншотом, убрать реальные имена, и оставить например в массиве JSON `[ ... ]` 2-3 элемента. Еще скажите, .NET Framework у вас, или .NET Core?

Comment: Добавил код и ссылку на JSON файл

Comment: .NET Framework или .NET Core? Покажите класс `DataJson`. От этого зависит качество ответа. Пока видно только что вы используете [`WebClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8), который согласно документации не рекомендуется использовать.

Comment: По структуре разных JSON файлов видно, что данные не следует смешивать в один массив, так как имена и фамилии могут повторяться, или что именно вам нужно сделать с данными, какую задачу вы хотите решить? От этого зависит конечное представление данных, то есть то, как будет выглядеть сам класс, хранящий загруженные данные

Comment: Добавил, спасибо за ваше терпение.

Comment: У меня был не один вопрос в последнем сообщении.

Comment: Программа должна строить график пройденных шагов выбранного из списка пользователя за 30 дней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как объединить данные вам уже ответили, я сейчас покажу лишь как поступил бы я на вашем месте и почему.

#### Загрузка данных

Вам уже пояснили другим ответом, что `WebClient` использовать сейчас, для новых разработок плохо, научитесь пользоваться `HttpClient`. Также стоит учесть тот факт, что данные вам попросту не нужны на компьютере, а если и нужны, то сохраняйте наверно уже "слепок" того, что получили после объединения.

Давайте сделаем некий метод, который будет отдавать нам каждого человека, которого мы можем обработать так, как нам захочется. И тут нам на помощь приходят нововведения, а именно [Асинхронные стримы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.8.php), которые в C#8 позволяют получать данные по мере поступления, а не пачками.

1. Сделаем класс, который будет содержать в себе данные одного файла с сервера, вы его уже сделали, я просто переделал под нужды этого проекта, а также запретил менять данные из вне (ведь нам не надо, чтобы в момент разработки мы случайно начали менять данные, полученные с сервера, верно?)

   ```
    class ServerData
    {
        public string User { get; }
        public int Steps { get; }
        public int Day { get; private set; }
        public void SetDay(int day) => Day = day;

        public ServerData(string user, int steps)
            => (User, Steps) = (user, steps);
    }
   ```

   `Day` тут служит неким идентификатором дня, когда пользователь сделал те самые шаги, ибо как оказалось не все пользователи начинали отчет с самого начала. Также вы спросите, а где статус и ранг? Ну в статусе я не вижу смысла, ибо он всегда один, а ранг дам простой подсчет кто сделал больше шагов, а это мы можем сделать сами.
2. Теперь сам метод получения, он будет примерно таким:

   ```
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    private async IAsyncEnumerable<ServerData> GetDataAsync()
    {
        int count = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            string data;

            try
            {
                data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"http://slova.by/JSON_test/Files/day{count}.json");
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e) when (e.Message.Contains("404"))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Файла нет на сервере");
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                break;
            }

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerData[]>(data);

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                item.SetDay(count);
                yield return item;
            }

            count++;
        }
    }
   ```

   Здесь по сути все просто, мы в бесконечном цикле берем данные до тех пор, пока сервер не выдаст ошибку (для примера я обработал 404 и все остальные, тут смотрите сами как поступить). В цикле мы пробуем получить ответ от сервера в виде `string` и если он успешный, то мы десериализуем это в массив `ServerData`, который в последующем перебираем (задав нужную дату файла) и отдаем наружу. Ну и в конце счетчик прибавляем.

#### Разбираем данные

Имея код выше мы можем теперь составить коллекцию всех пользователей в удобном нам виде, который позволит удобно просматривать и сортировать данные.

1. Создадим класс одного человека. В него мы поместим ФИО, а также коллекцию пройденных шагов и в какой день. Каждый шаг пусть будет отдельным классом.

   ```
    class DaySteps
    {
        public int Day { get; }
        public int Steps { get; }
        public DaySteps(int day, int steps) => (Day, Steps) = (day, steps);
    }

    class User
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public List<DaySteps> Steps { get; }
        public User(string name) => (Name, Steps) = (name, new List<DaySteps>());
        public bool HasADay(int day) => Steps.Any(x => x.Day == day);
    }
   ```

   `HasADay` - это предикат, который вернет `true`, если пользователь вел учет шагов в указанный день.
2. Берем теперь данные с сервера и формируем коллекцию людей:

   ```
    private List<User> Users { get; } = new List<User>();
    public async Task<UsersManager> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        await foreach (var data in GetDataAsync())
        {
            if (!Users.Any(x => x.Name == data.User))
            {
                var user = new User(data.User);
                user.Steps.Add(new DaySteps(data.Day, data.Steps));
                Users.Add(user);
            }
            else
            {
                var user = Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == data.User);
                user.Steps.Add(new DaySteps(data.Day, data.Steps));
            }
        }

        return this;
    }
   ```

   Тут я думаю все предельно просто: есть человек - ищем, добавляем новый день с новыми шагами. Нету - добавляем. Единственное что может смутить, так это `return this`, так вот, я это сделал для удобства, чтобы потом можно было использовать так называемый "цепочный вызов".

Все, теперь у нас есть коллекция с объединенными данными по всем пользователям (как вы и просили).

#### Работа с данными

Теперь мы сами хозяева данных и в праве сами с ними как угодно распоряжаться, пару примеров:

- Сериализуем в один JSON:

  ```
  public void ToJSON(string file) 
        => File.WriteAllText(file, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Users, Formatting.Indented));
  ```
- Выводи рейтинг за указанный день (прям как на сайте):

  ```
  public UsersManager PrintTop(int day)
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"--- Рейтинг за {day} день ---");
      var users = Users.Where(x => x.HasADay(day))
          .Select(x => (x.Name, x.Steps.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Day == day).Steps))
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Steps)
          .ToList();

      for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
      {
          var user = users[i];
          Console.WriteLine($"[{i + 1}] {user.Name}: {user.Steps}");
      }

      return this;
  }
  ```

Ну и так далее, примеров может быть много. Вызов этого всего будет тогда такой:

```
var manager = new UsersManager();
(await manager.LoadDataAsync()).PrintTop(15).ToJSON("Data.json");
```

Что даст нам файл JSON с полностью объединенными данными и выведет в консоль топ

[image: TopUsers]

Как видите, если взять чуть больше и сделать некий комбайн (я это вовсе делал на коленке, да криво), получится весьма годный источник данных с которым удобно будет работать, так что удачи в изучении C#!

<sup>P.S. Не гнался за решением конкретно поставленной задачи, хотел лишь показать как можно поступить.</sup>

Comment: Была б моя воля, я б на каждый вопрос на восьмом шарпе отвечал. :) Очень хороший пример по `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: Кстати, `JsonConvert` я бы тоже в `try` засунул.

Comment: @aepot Тоже верно, но это пусть будет на совести автора.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала предлагаю использовать `HttpClient` вместо `WebClient`, хотя-бы потому что [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) указано, что:

> Не рекомендуется использовать класс `WebClient` для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте класс `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

Вторая причина - у `HttpClient` толковое современное асинхронное API.

1. Создайте [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) отдельно, потому что

> `HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.

```csharp
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

2. Реализуйте метод загрузки

```csharp
private async Task<List<JsonData>> LoadJsonDataAsync(url)
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonData>>(responseText);
    }
}
```

3. Грузите

```csharp
private async Task LoadAllDataAsync()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<JsonData>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<JsonData>>();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++);
        {
            string fileName = $"day{i}.json";
            data.Add(fileName, await LoadJsonDataAsync($"http://slova.by/JSON_test/Files/{fileName}"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Обработайте здесь вероятное исключение.
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<JsonData>> pair in data)
    {
        // здесь можно что-то с данными сделать, pair.Key - имя файла, pair.Value - список
    } 
}
```

Подробнее про асинхронное программирование можно почитать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.3.php) или [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async)

Answer (score 0):

Для случая локального хранения файлов.

```
using System.Linq;

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_HERE");
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    // DO Something...
}
```

если у Вас удаленный репозиторий то нужно сначала синхронизировать каталоги
(локальный, удаленный) и сделать как код выше но уже делать сортировку по имени `.OrderBy(p => p.FileName)` или как вам удобно

Обновлено. А вообще держите данные по клиенту также как и есть и тогда очерёдность будет определяться так как вы хотите.

для каждого файла

1. считываете файл
2. парсите данные
3. для каждой записи в файле добавить/обновить информацию за считанный день (ключ) по клиенту в общий список.

AllUserData = {
User1: {
day1: DataJson,
day2: DataJson,
...
dayn: DataJson,
}

,
......

UserK: {
day2: DataJson,
...
dayj: DataJson,
}
.....
}

Comment: Очевидно, ваш ответ не подходит для автора вопроса.

Comment: Ну какой вопрос, бывает и такое как не странно. Я ответил как понял, решать автору что делать. Если изменять вопрос каждые несколько минут то что говорить об ответе который был дан час назад.

Comment: Я не спорю, но когда вас хаказчик просит накодить фичу, вы тоже делаете реализацию "как поняли", или все-таки задаете уточняющие вопросы?

Comment: Да, но я не имею привычки указывать заказчику что делать.

Comment: Я делаю так как понял. Потому что объяснять или рассказывать заказчику смысла нет. Нужно бысро показать - это называется демонстрация и выслушать его замечания это называется продуктивная работа с клиентом. Он всё равно оплатит всё, разницы нет и времени на обсуждения тоже. Как показывает мне моя практика проект который заказывается и который в конце это разные проекты.

Comment: Я тоже раньше так делал, но потом понял, что эта плохая идея, теперь зарабатываю в 2 раза больше. По моему подходу сначала надо выяснить, что делать, а только потом делать (в рамках разумного, конечно же). При таком подходе, переделывать придется всего 3 раза, а не 33, к тому же вероятность попасть в ожидания заказчика выше, а при попадании в ожидания к тебе появляется уважение как к специалисту. А у вас как-то наоборот получается. Но вам конечно же виднее, у каждого своя философия по таким вопросам.

Comment: Вы программируете или обсуждаете, вы программист или бизнесмен? Понимаете я программирую когда дают задание если вопросы есть задаю если нет то выполняю. Так вот мне приходит задание я его делаю, если что-то не верно то минус не мне а BA или Owner. Я максимально придерживаюсь задания если что-то там не првильно (логика, слова ....) это не мои проблемы. Я работник которому платят за работу по часам, если б платили по проектно или сдельно то возможно я с вами согласился, а 3 или 33 мне все равно сколько раз это не мои проблемы.

Comment: от того сколько раз я переделаю их переделанное задание это их проблемы а не мои.

Comment: и К вопросу было время я тоже выяснял и указывал их пробелы. В итоге меня сократили со словами мол много якобы спорит, так что я больше так не делаю.

Comment: На SO у вас нет BA, который будет задавать вопросы овнеру, чтобы в результате у вас была сверкающая спека для "сел и пили". Нет смысла сравнивать закрытие тасков с логированием времени с тем, что происходит здесь. Здесь за экономию вашего времени и за качество ваших ответов вы отвечаете сами, а не BA или Product Owner. Если вам нравится писать ответы в стиле fire-and-forget - пожалуйста, ваше право. Я просто намекнул на ситуативную сомнительность данной перспективы.

Comment: Вы думаете о каких-то облачных перспективах когда вам ясно? Человек задал вопрос есть файлы нужно отсортировать данные, а вы про асинхронное программирование. Ну про100 прелесть а не логика. У вас когда проект заказывают вы всегда делаете паровоз по ходу потому что это правильно и у вас легко получается?

Comment: А что изначально было не понятно в вопросе? Вполне понятная задача, которая гласит "Есть JSON данные в разных файлах, надо это загрузить в одно целое", вы же показываете как получить из папки файлы, это соответствует поставленной задаче? После, да, автор добавил, что данные вовсе на сервере и можно избежать их загрузки на диск, но это не изменило радикально вопрос, он как был про одно, так и остался. Вы же, как я вам уже говорил, просто "заткнули" его своим неверным ответом, а это на данном ресурсе чревато тем, что знающий может попросту не зайти, ибо есть ответ и зачем тратить ему свое время?